# Exposing database query parameters via REST interface

Tags: rest, mongodb

I have the basics of a REST service done, with "standard" list and GET/POST/PUT/DELETE verbs implemented around my nouns.

However, the client base I'm working with also wants to have more powerful operations.  I'm using Mongo DB on the back-end, and it'd be easy to expose an "update" operation.  [This page](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating) describes how Mongo can do updates.

It'd be easy to write a page that takes a couple of JSON/XML/whatever arguments for the "criteria" and the "objNew" parts of the Mongo update function.  Maybe I make a page like http://myserver.com/collection/update that takes a POST (or PUT?) request, with a request body that contains that data.  Scrub the input for malicious querying and to enforce security, and we're done.  Piece of cake.

My question is: what's the "best" way to expose this in a RESTful manner?  Obviously, the approach I described above isn't kosher because "update" isn't a noun.  This sort of thing seems much more suitable for a SOAP/RPC method, but the rest of the service is already using REST over HTTP, and I don't want users to have to make two different types of calls.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since as you're aware it isn't a good fit for REST, you're just going to have to do your best and invent a standard to make it work. Mongo's update functionality is so far removed from REST, I'd actually allow PUTs on the collection. Ignore the parameters in my examples, I haven't thought too hard about them.

- PUT collection?set={field:value}
- PUT collection?pop={field:1}

Or:

- PUT collection/pop?field=1

Answer (score 2):

Typically, I would handle this as:

- url/collection
- url/collection/item
- GET collection: Returns a representation of the collection resource
- GET collection/item: Returns a representation of the item resource
  (optional URI params for content-types: json, xml, txt, etc)
- POST collection/: Creates a new item (if via XML, I use XSD to validate)
- PUT collection/item: Update an existing item
- DELETE collection/item: Delete an existing item

Does that help?

Comment: wouldn't that be: "POST collection: Creates a new item, redirects to collection/item"

Comment: I have that much already set up.  However, if you check the mongo doc I linked to, that update function provides much more functionality than the above-described REST setup. I basically want to expose the update function over HTTP, and I'm not sure about the clearest/"best" way to do it.